# Can locomotion of a Weeping Angel be recorded using cam?

Tags: doctor-who

Weeping Angels are fastest creatures in existence. They are in quantum lock when someone sees them. You blink and they are gone. So, nobody is able to see their locomotion.

But, quantum lock isn't applied when light rays falls on them in general (as long as someone isn't seeing them). Can I use a cam to capture their motion?

Would placing a cam initiate quantum lock? Or, their motion is faster than light to go beyond capability of any cam? Or, I would be successful?

Has this ever been mentioned in the canon? Or, a logical reasoning based on canon would be fine.

Comment: What is your reference for the Weeping Angels being the fastest creatures in existence?

Comment: Would you really want to?  Remember what happened to Amy when she watched a cam of an Angel.. yikes!

Comment: @MeatTrademark It was told by The Doctor in the Sally Sparrow episode. But, it may be one of fastest creatures in existence.

Comment: I felt that my answer to this one was pretty convincing. Is there anything else you'd like me to add before considering an acceptance?

Comment: There are other real quantum philosophical questions we can ask. "If you put a Weeping Angel in a box with Schroedinger's Cat, does the cat get out alive?" "If a Weeping Angel sees a tree fall in the forest, does it make a sound?"

Answer (score 11):

This issue has been discussed both within the TV series and the prose novels that lead on;

Simply put, a weeping angel can exist as an **independent entity** within a camera image or video footage. If you view that footage, the angel becomes frozen but as soon as it's not being observed, the Angel can move freely within the frame as well as exit the monitor you're using to observe it on.

We see this most clearly in the TV episode ["Time of Angels"](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/31-4.htm)

> **AMY:** *Doctor Song? Did you have more than one clip of the Angel?*
>
> **RIVER:** *No, just the four seconds.*
>
> (The Angel is now looking straight at the viewer, hands completely
>   lowered. The time stamp has moved as far as 00:11:28:04 before jumping
>   back to 00:11:24:23. **When Amy looks at the monitor again, it is closer
>   to the camera.** The module door closes and locks behind her.)
>
> (Amy tries turning off the monitor, but it comes back on again, and
>   again, and again. She moves close to the monitor.)
>
> **AMY:** ***But you're just a recording. You can't move.***  (She tries to pull
>   out the lead to the monitor. When she looks back up, the Angel is up
>   close to the camera, but the time stamp is still running through the
>   same four seconds.)
>
> **AMY:** *Doctor?*
>
> (Amy cannot open the door. The Angel's mouth is open.)
>
> **AMY:** *Doctor!*

Comment: The security cam captured just image of standing Angel which became Angel itself. I am asking whether locomotion can be recorded or not...

Comment: No. If you look at the image of an angel, it'll cease to move

Comment: That's because image is an Angel.

Comment: Yes you can capture the locomotion of a weeping angel.  If you watch the video, the angel will cease moving, however if you play the video without watching the angel will capture you.